# How to print consecutive numbers for cells that contain numbers?

Tags: excel-formula

I have numbers and empty values in column A. I'm trying to get a formula (Excel 365) to show consecutive numbers each time a number appears and show "EMPTY" if
there is no value in column A.

I've tried 2 formulas, with the outputs as shown in image below.

```
In B1: =IF(ISNUMBER(A1),ROW(A1),"EMPTY"), and copy down.
In C1: =IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A10),ROW(A1),"EMPTY")
```

My expected output would be as in column D.

[image]

Thanks for any help with a formula to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MS365 you can use

```
=BYROW(A1:A10,LAMBDA(rng,IF(ISNUMBER(rng),COUNT($A$1:rng),"EMPTY")))
```

as a spill formula:

[image: Screenshot illustrating formula proposed]

(the Excel 2019 approach would have been

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),COUNT($A$1:A1),"EMPTY")
```

and copied down)

Comment: Great, great again. It works correctly as I was looking for. It seems to be easier (shorter) in Excel 2019.

Comment: @RasecMalkic in this case, yes: `COUNT(A1:A10)` would return a single result, but the `BYROW`/`LAMBDA` construct means the `COUNT()` function will return a single result _per row_ (of `A1:A10`). A perhaps simpler MS365 solution would be `=MAP(A1:A10,LAMBDA(r,IF(ISNUMBER(r),COUNT(A1:r),"EMPTY")))`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?
if u need something le me know,
thanks :)

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,A1:A9,ROW(A1)),"EMPTY") **and copy down
```

[image]